# Check that entire list of files exist via ssh and condition if so

Tags: bash, ssh, files

I have a list of files that **must** exist in a remote directory before I send out a confirmation email. For example, my list is: `file_list=example.txt testfile.txt`. I know how to test if each *individual* file exists as such:

```
ssh here@ip.addr "test -e /path/to/file/example.txt"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo -e "Email body" | mail -s "File exists." "some.email@email.com"
fi
```

But how can I hit each file in the list and confirm that **all files** exist in this remote directory? Say three out of four were successfully pushed via `sftp`, I'd need to exit with an e-mail error to my group only saying go check it out rather than proceeding to email the client that all files are available. The logic is perhaps something like:

```
ssh here@ip.addr "test - [$file_list]"
if [they all exist]; then
  successful -- email the client
else
  error -- email your group
  exit
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* try to set up an array on the remote side of a single ssh connection and loop through it; if the list of files is static and you can drop a shell script on the remote side, calling it may be easiest. Otherwise, you could set the array up locally and loop over it, ssh'ing in each time to test for the file's existence:

```
files=(example.txt testfile.txt)
ok=0
for file in "${files[@]}"
do
  ssh here@ip.addr test -e "$file" && ((ok++))
done
if [ $ok -eq ${#files[@]} ]
then
  success, all $ok files made it
else
  failure, only $ok files made it
fi
```

Comment: I'm getting a binary operator error after the `ssh` step but this is essentially what I want -- thanks! The error is `test: /remote/path/example.txt: binary operator expected`.

Comment: `ssh here@ip.addr test -e "$file" && ((ok++))` should be `ssh here@ip.addr 'test -e "$file" && ((ok++))'` Forgot quotes :P

Comment: Single-quoting the entire thing will prevent expansion of $file

Comment: Single quoting actually does not work for me -- the ANSWER ABOVE works:  `ssh here@ip.addr test -e "$dir/$date/$file" && ((ok++))`. My array would not take my `file_list` i.e. `files=($file_list)` so I had to explicitly define that array.

Answer (score 0):

Set the variable `file` and `file1` and add the names of the files.

```
file="/path/to/testfile.txt"
file1="/path/to/example.txt"

ssh here@ip.addr
if [[ -f "$file" && -f "$file1" ]]; then
    echo -e "Email body" | mail -s "File exists." "some.email@email.com"
else
  echo -e "Email body" | mail -s "File does not exists." "some.email@email.com"
  exit
fi
```

> `-f` : Return true value if file exists and is a regular file.

Comment: This is a little too much hard coding. The file names and numbers change daily, so `-f file1`, `-f file2`, `etc.` is going to vary greatly.